# The set of bounded divergent sequences of a metric space with no isolated points is dense

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a metric space with no isolated points and denote by $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb N, M)$ the set of bounded functions $f:\Bbb N\to M$. Show that the set $D\subset\mathcal{B}(\Bbb N, M)$ of bounded divergent sequences is dense in $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb N, M)$.

Comment: You need to endow $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{N},M)$ with a topology before your question will make sense. Probably you want the topology generated by the sup norm. For instance if $M=\mathbb{R}$ then the space is just $\ell_\infty$, in which case the proof is easy by letting $y=(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\cdots)$ and showing that $x+\epsilon y\in D$ with $x+\epsilon y\to x$ for any convergent $x$. For general $M$, the proof is no doubt very similar.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{N},M)$ is supposed to be endowed with the sup norm.  (The statement isn't true for an arbitrary topology.)

Suppose $x_n\to x\in M$.  Since $M$ contains no isolated points there exists $y\in M$ which is $\epsilon/2$-close to $x$ but is distinct from $x$.  Now find $N$ so that $x_n$ is $\epsilon/2$-close to $x$ for all $n\geq N$. Note that $y$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x_n$ for all $n\geq N$ by the triangle inequality.  Consider the sequences $$\textbf{y}_\epsilon=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N,x,y,x,y,x,y,\cdots).$$
and
$$\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots).$$
Then $\textbf{y}_\epsilon\to\textbf{x}$ with each $\textbf{y}_\epsilon\in D$.